# SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48(address already in use), i already detached Rserve package, but it still shows this error

Tags: java, r, rserve

i am trying to connect R with java
i didn`t use Rstudio and i went through the process on Macbook Terminal
here's what i did

```
R
library(Rserve)
Rserve(args="--no-save")
```

and after this, it shows

```
Rserv started in daemon mode.
SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48(address already in use)
```

i tried to deatch("packages:Rserve",TRUE) and use Search() on R, it shows me

```
search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

one thing i know is that when i completely reboot my macbook, it doesn`t show me Sock_Error message, but i wanna resolve this without rebooting my laptop

thanks in advance!

Comment: The port is already bound to a process. Probably an earlier run of your project that didn't terminate?

Comment: yeah, i thought so. so i finally resolved this issue

Comment: how did you resolve this issue?